# How does a remote connection knows it's endpoint inside a LAN?

Tags: computer-networks

I'm very curious about anything related to packet headers since im not well aware of how TCP/UDP protocols identify it's connection endpoint after a public IP is addressed. As for today I know the port will identify the process, but what happens when typically more than one computer is working over the same public IP and ports? No way more than one computer can listen to the same port? It is ultimately required to use more than one public address?

I guess i'm missing something very ridiculous here, and since its becoming a bit harder for me to find such details on internet I end up on here. Can someone clear me this in a nutshell?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. What do you mean by "after a public IP is addressed" or "working over the same public IP and ports"? Perhaps the answer that you're looking for is that a connection is identified by the IP address and port number at both endpoints?